# MYSQL Query Count the Number of Distinct Values Per Day For Past 7 Days

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the number of records per day for the last 7 days, however, the ip must be unique per day (ip cannot be counted twice per day).

This is my query so far. As of right now, it counts the number of records per day but does not check that the ip is unique.

```
SELECT extract( DAY FROM date_visited ) AS theDay, 
    count( * ) AS numberOfItems 
    FROM table 
    WHERE `date_visited` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
    GROUP BY extract( DAY FROM date_visited )
```

This Returns the total per day, not the number of unique ip's per day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS numberOfItems
```

SQL is pretty cool that way.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT ip) AS numberOfItems FROM stattracker WHERE `date_visited` >= DATE_SU' at line 2

Comment: Thank you @Ollie Jones, I am getting an error when I make the suggested adjustment.  I haven't been able to execute this properly.  Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: You didn't say the name of your ip column. So I guessed. Also, I should have put no space between the word `COUNT` and the parenthesis